# Instagram игнорирует запросы с Heroku, Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, бот

Делаю бота на Python, использую selenium. Суть бота заключается в том, что ему нужно подписываться на подписчиков заданного аккаунта. Работает он по принципу:

```
InputLogin = browser.find_element_by_xpath('Xpath поля для логина').clear()
InputLogin.send_keys(username)
```

На компе всё работает идеально, однако, когда пытаюсь деплоить на Heroku работать перестает и в логах выдаёт Traceback:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a/span"}
```

Начал отладку с помощью ультрасовременных технологий: print().
Решил вывести код страницы с помощью print(browser.page_source) и обнаружил, что он выводит тег body и следующий за ним какой-то div. Дальше этого div он не идет.

Прогуглив эту штуку нашел, что, возможно, Instagram на запросы с Heroku выдаёт страницу заглушку. Посидел, подумал, что, по идее, у Heroku должен быть один ip, с которого он посылает запросы, и, который находится у Instagram в черном списке, поэтому решил использовать прокси, однако это не помогло.

Ёще, от безысходности, проскочила мысль, что если подгрузить через selenium cookie, может что и сработает, но увы и ах -- не прокатило. И теперь, собственно, вопрос/просьба: подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно  залогиниться в инстаграме через бота, который размещен на Heroku.

Comment: Есть предположение, что он игнорирует запросы на основе http- заголовков. То есть, если хорошо, качественно подделать заголовки - то сможете залогиниться. Например, обязательно указывать корректный user-agent. Но если на компе всё работает - вполе возможно, действительно бан по ip. А еще он может "новому пользователю" подсовывать капчу от гугла, например.

Comment: @s-h, А можете рассказать, пожалуйста, подробнее про подделывание http заголовков. User_Agent использую, также использую следующие опции:

`op.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
op.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
op.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
op.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
op.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
op.add_argument("--start-maximized")
op.add_argument('--headless')
op.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
op.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
op.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
op.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')`

Comment: Мне кажется, в первую очередь надо всё таки проверить, не выдёт ли инстаграмм страницу - заглушку или страницу с капчей при заходе с Heroku. Если локально всё работает, а при переносе на Heroku не работает - то, возможно, дело не в заголовках... В общем, надо спосмощью print() страницу, выдаваемую Heroku сохранить и потом как то открыть сохранённый файл - и посмотреть, что же там видно :-)

Comment: С помощью print(browser.pager_source) я вывожу код, поскольку я ищу элементы по xpath, меня интересует html, а из того html, что выводится есть только `<body class="" style="">
<div id="react-root"></div>` На этом html заканчивается и начинается js. Попробовал через `browser.save_screenshot()` сделать скриншот и открыть через консоль на Heroku, но ls говорит, что кроме файлов, что я деплоил с гита, там ничего нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что еще можно попробовать.

Comment: Можно попробовать на Heroku запустить скрипт - прокси и через этот прокси сходить на инстаграмм. Только ходить надо или в  инкогнито, или вообще другим чистеньким браузером (которым Вы никогад в жизни на инстеграмм не заходили) - иначе эксперимент не будет чистым. Важно увидеть, что показывает барузер, без этого все усилия - бессмысленны